# How to get the Clicked ID and output that ID data in another page

Tags: theme-development, get-the-id

I am creating a WordPress theme. I created `single.php`, in which I have a button called "Watch Now".

When "Watch Now" is clicked, it gets the ID of the current/clicked post dynamically using the function `get_the_ID()`. When it goes to another page (`receive.php`), I want to output that ID data, i.e. image of that ID, content of that ID, title and other things. However, when I click "Watch Now", it leads me to `receive.php` with this error:

> Error 404 - Page Not Found

Receive.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

            <div class="entry">

                <?php the_content(); ?>
                   <a href="recieve.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Watch Now</a> 
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                <?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', ''); ?>

            </div>

            <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>

        </div>

    <?php comments_template(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `$id` is undefined, and `revieve.php` is probably not where you expect it.

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of this exercise? Why don't you just show the post in single.php template? You already told WordPress that you want to see the post by clicking on post's title on archive or blog page. Why to add an unnecessary step when all you need is provided by WordPress? I would help if I knew the logic behind it.

Comment: The reason for 404 error is simple. The link "Watch Now" in receive.php script points to receive.php located in root of the site. If this script belongs to your theme it shouldn't be there in a first place. All template tags within this script have no meaning as the script knows nothing about WordPress environment.